# What is the subject of statistics called if the subject is used to studying if the statistic formulated fit the actual data?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, terminology

What is the subject of statistics called if the subject is used to studying if a statistical model formulated fit the actual data?

If there are more than one general subject to study this, name all of them.

I was thinking that curve fitting and theory of reliability responsible for that. If so, what else?

Comment: "Emprical?" Not really a branch of statistics, though. Maybe "a posteriori", usually used in economics, in which a theory is derived from the data, rather than "a priori" in which a theory is posted first, then data is used to validate or invalidate. Hard to list all a posteriori approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about how well a model fits data (not sure what it would mean to say a "statistic" fits the data), that would be [goodness of fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit).

Comment: This site has a tag for `goodness-of-fit`, with nearly 400 questions presently tagged with that topic.